# Android app accessing locked down phone dialler

Tags: android, android-dialer

My company has written an android driver app (for making deliveries) from which the driver can select a 'call' button to dial the customer they are delivering to. I know how to change the intent to auto dial the number instead of the user having to manually initiate the call but I would like to know if there is a way of somehow locking the dialler down in some way.

Best solutions would be to either a) ensure that the phone returns to the drivers app after the call hangs up, or b) disabling the number pad on the dialler so they cannot call any other numbers.

I have searched through the available dialler apps on play store to see if there was anything suitable but I could not find anything. I have searched the forums (which is how I found the ACTION.CALL intent) but not really found a solution yet.

The app is written with PHP and javascript.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance, 
Ant.

Comment: this is not related to `php` tag as your question doesn't include php code nor any question about php, assigning wrong tags waste time of people who are trying to help

Comment: oh well excuse me for making an error on my first ever post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on their personal phone, or on a device you give them?  If its a personal phone, no.  If its a device you give them-  what you really want is a kiosk app.  You could install your own softphone that doesn't allow dialing (although you should probably add a 911 button for emergencies) and block the user from installing any other dialers via DeviceManager apis (you'd have to be the device owner, but as its a device you physically control that's no problem).

Of course doing kiosk mode is really diving through deep apis that almost nobody uses.  I wouldn't recommend it without an android expert on your team.

Outisde of kiosk mode and a complete lockdown of your device-  no there is no way.  Because the dialer is just an app, there's no way to force it to have certain features.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - It is a device we supply and it has a laucher installed that either locks down the phone to a few apps or has a kiosk mode with a single app. They do need to run 2 or 3 apps on the device so the kiosk mode is no good for this situation. I will look into the possibility of our own dialer. Thanks.